# Эффекты слайдера

Tags: jquery

Бодрого всем дня или ночи.
Есть такой вот слайдер 
[jCarousel Lite](http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/) на JQuery.
Вопрос в том, есть ли у него какие-то другие эффекты анимации?
Затухание или ещё что-то в том же роде?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

когда возникают такие вопросы, и документации недостаточно, смотрите в код.
Именно в этом слайдере код такой:

```
ul.animate(
                animCss == "left" ? { left: -(curr*liSize) } : { top: -(curr*liSize) } , o.speed, o.easing,
…
```

то есть, как видим, меняется свойство css left или top в зависимости от переданных опций. Это жёстко записано в коде. Значит, этот плагин умеет только сдвигать контент в сторону, но не затухать его.

Если вам нужен другой эффект, не предусмотренный в плагине изначально, ничто не мешает модифицировать код и менять более иное свойство css.